# How does subversion check file differences between working copy & server?

Tags: svn

I am trying to understand how svn works at the socket level when checking differences between the working copy and the last revision on the server.

I have been following this article:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_ra_svn/protocol

Which explains the protocol but I am still unclear on how subversion checks differences when you issue a "svn status".

I am looking for a way I can replicate this behaviour as is I was implementing my own SVN client.

Comment: svn status uses the pristine copies of the downloaded files under the .svn directory to compare them against - it doesn't issue a diff I don't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, AFAIK.

When you run `svn st`, the timestamp of the WC copy of the file is checked against the timestamp of the last time you ran `svn update` on the WC (the pristine copy). If they differ, a checksum of the file is calculated and compared against a checksum of the pristine copy. If that differs, the diff algorithm calculates the differences.

When you run `svn st -u`, the client says to the server "my working copy is at revision X, what items have changed since then?" (note: **not** "what changes have happened" but rather a simple "give me a list of what items *have* changed") and the server returns a list (including any locks that exist). No other diffing (that I'm aware of) happens.